# AngularJS automatic isn't working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am writing a client-side application with AngularJS for fun. In a part of the application it's supposed to show all the applicants in a table, automatically fetched from my JSON array. But it isn't working.

This is my code:

```js
//engine.js

(function(){
    angular
        .module("resumeBase", []);
})();

//controllers.js

(function(){
    angular
        .module("resumeBase")
        .controller("tabularList", listController);

        function listController() {
            var vm = this;
            vm.data = applicants;
        }

        var applicants = [
            {
                firstname: "Nima",
                lastname: "Bavari",
                evaluation: 5,
                category: "IT & Computers",
                fileLocation: "",
                empConfirmed: "found",
                confirmTime: "01-01-2017",
                employer: "EnDATA",
                payConfirmed: "yes"
            }
        ]
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="resumeBase">
    <head>
        <title>::Search Entries::</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/main.css" />
    </head><body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/engine.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/controllers.js"></script>
        <div id="container" ng-controller="tabularList">
            <hr />
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Firstname</th>
                    <th>Lastname</th>
                    <th>Evaluation</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Resume</th>
                    <th>Found Job?</th>
                    <th>Date and Time</th>
                    <th>Employer</th>
                    <th>Paid Us?</th>
                </tr>

                <tr ng-repeat="item in tabularList.data">
                    <td>{{item.firstname}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.lastname}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.evaluation}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.category}}</td>
                    <td><a ng-href="{{item.fileLocation}}" target="blank">{{item.fileLocation}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{item.empConfirmed}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.confirmTime}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.employer}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.payConfirmed}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            [<a href="index.php">Add New Entry</a>]
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What do you recommend? Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the **`controller as syntax`**, Just change your HTML as,

```
  <div id="container" ng-controller="tabularList as vm">
```

also,

```
 <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.data">
```

**DEMO**

```js
//engine.js

(function(){
    angular
        .module("resumeBase", []);
})();

//controllers.js

(function(){
    angular
        .module("resumeBase")
        .controller("tabularList", listController);

        function listController() {
            var vm = this;
            vm.data = applicants;
        }

        var applicants = [
            {
                firstname: "Nima",
                lastname: "Bavari",
                evaluation: 5,
                category: "IT & Computers",
                fileLocation: "",
                empConfirmed: "found",
                confirmTime: "01-01-2017",
                employer: "EnDATA",
                payConfirmed: "yes"
            }
        ]
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="resumeBase">
    <head>
        <title>::Search Entries::</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/main.css" />
    </head><body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
         <div id="container" ng-controller="tabularList as vm">
            <hr />
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Firstname</th>
                    <th>Lastname</th>
                    <th>Evaluation</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Resume</th>
                    <th>Found Job?</th>
                    <th>Date and Time</th>
                    <th>Employer</th>
                    <th>Paid Us?</th>
                </tr>

                <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.data">
                    <td>{{item.firstname}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.lastname}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.evaluation}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.category}}</td>
                    <td><a ng-href="{{item.fileLocation}}" target="blank">{{item.fileLocation}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{item.empConfirmed}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.confirmTime}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.employer}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.payConfirmed}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            [<a href="index.php">Add New Entry</a>]
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you check the demo

Comment: nothing to do with wamp, no those are the two changes. do you see any errors

Comment: Thanks a lot. Turns out I was an idiot and typed now() instead of new Date()